# Create exhaustive list from concatenated category values and category value counts

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Given an example table below:

```
Category Value  Category Value Count
A               4
B               2
C               0
D               3
E               1
```

I need to create a list of concatenated text with the Category Value column and Category Value Count columns as shown below. Note the Category Value is repeated by the times based on the Category Value Count starting from 1 to MAX(Category Value Count). Category Value cells with Category Values Count equal to 0 should not be included in the list.

```
Result
A1
A2
A3
A4
B1
B2
D1
D2
D3
E1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
A                B                      C
Category Value   Category Value Count   Result
A                4                      A1
B                2                      A2
C                0                      A3
D                3                      A4
E                1                      B1
                                        B2
                                        D1
                                        D2
                                        D3
                                        E1
```

It is an interesting and challenging question.

Here is a formula solution to solve it I have:

Assume data housed in `A1:B6` with header, "Result" in Column C

In C2, formula copied down :

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A$2:A$6,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(A$2:A$6)-ROW(A$1)/(B$2:B$6>=COLUMN($1:$1)),ROWS($1:1)))&0+RIGHT(AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($2:$6)/1%+COLUMN($1:$1)/(B$2:B$6>=COLUMN($1:$1)),ROWS($1:1)),2),"")
```